# how do I assign a function to a declared function that has already been defined

Tags: c++, function, oop

In my C++ file OneDSystem.cpp I have the following:

```cpp
OneDSystem::OneDSystem()
{
    this->Particle = OneDParticle();
    this->potential = &SHOPotential; // problem here.
    this->MAXPOS = this->Particle.get().at(0);
    this->MAXVEL = this->Quadratic(2 / this->Particle.get_mass(), 0.0, PotentialEnergy(this->MAXPOS));
}

// Works perfect
OneDSystem::OneDSystem(const OneDParticle particle, double(*potential)(double, double))
{
    this->Particle = particle;
    this->potential = potential;
    this->MAXPOS = this->Particle.get().at(0);
    this->MAXVEL = this->Quadratic(2 / this->Particle.get_mass(), 0.0, PotentialEnergy(this->MAXPOS));

// other code...
}

double OneDSystem::SHOPotential(double mass, double position) { return 0.5 * position * position / mass; }
```

OneDSystem.hpp

```
class OneDSystem
{
private:
    double (*potential)(double, double);
    OneDParticle Particle;
    double MAXPOS, MAXVEL;

    double SHOPotential(double mass, double position);
    // other methods

public:
    OneDSystem();
    OneDSystem(const OneDParticle Particle, double (*potential)(double,double));
};
```

the function `potential` given in the function is to be defined later when the `OneDSystem` is initialized. This works great until I want to make the default constructor.

In short how do assign a function that has already been defined already.

P.S. Sorry if I need to add more in I was trying to keep it as snippet-y as possible.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the default constructor to set `potential` to the class version of the function?

Comment: Yes that is what I want but I keep getting: C++ a value of type double (OneDSystem::*)(double,double) cannot be assigned to an entity of type double(*)(double,double). Maybe I am just missing something and being stupid :/

Comment: You have `double (*potential)(double, double);` but you are trying to set that with a `double OneDSystem::SHOPotential(double mass, double position);` member function.  That's a square peg and a round hole.  They don't fit.  Make the member function a class function, by putting `static` in front of it.

Comment: Your class version of `SHOPotential` takes an implied argument of `this` and so its signature does not match. If you do not need to access any members from the default implementation, you could make it `static`.

Comment: Making it static seems the right thing todo, but if you want client code to be able to select one of the methods, they should also be public

Comment: Can you use a `std::function<double(double, double)>` instead of a raw function pointer? Using that with `std::bind()` or `[this](...){ return this->SHOPotential(...); }` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the class implementation static.

OneDSystem.hpp

```
class OneDSystem
{
private:
    double (*potential)(double, double);
    OneDParticle Particle;
    double MAXPOS, MAXVEL;

    static double SHOPotential(double mass, double position);

public:
    OneDSystem();
    OneDSystem(const OneDParticle Particle, double (*potential)(double,double));
};
```

OneDSystem.cpp:

```
OneDSystem::OneDSystem()
{
    this->Particle = OneDParticle();
    this->potential = &OneDSystem::SHOPotential;
    this->MAXPOS = this->Particle.get().at(0);
    this->MAXVEL = this->Quadratic(2 / this->Particle.get_mass(), 0.0, PotentialEnergy(this->MAXPOS));
}
```